# How do I make this sentence sound clearer?

Tags: grammar, commas

How do I make this sentence sound clearer:

> I was rereading the mail that you sent me yesterday.

I'm referring to a mail that was sent a while back which I was rereading.
This sounds like I was rereading a mail which was sent the day before.

Edit: I was wondering if there was anyway to make it sound clearer while keeping the word "yesterday" at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Yesterday, while re-reading your earlier email, ... - does this meet your needs? You can even say "Yesterday, while re-reading the attached email" for greater clarity.

Comment: This question has been flagged by some users as a proofreading request, when in fact a specific area of concern has been identified by the OP. The question appears to be on-topic as set out by [help].

Comment: Yesterday I was rereading the mail that you sent me.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

> Yesterday, while re-reading your earlier email, ...

or:

> Yesterday, while re-reading the attached email, ...

for greater clarity.